# How do i build an AppBar that has a background image and overlay text on it and a TabBar on the bottom which gets pinned on scroll?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, tabbar, appbar

I want to build something that is similar to the Masterclass app which has a background image and a tab bar which gets pinned to the top while scrolling down and the background image has overlay text which scrolls without affecting the background image. I want to replicate this in Flutter and need some help. Anyone who has an idea to replicate this UI would be of significant help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set up the static background image, we need to use the Stack widget which allows to layer its children. And the NestedScrollView widget for nested scroll views. You can find explanation and code [here](https://flutter-love.com/clone-de-lapplication-mobile-de-masterclass/)

Comment: Actually we can do that by implementing a sliver app bar and using the flexible space to implement the background image, i found out the solution through some research.